# Haskell Alex - regex matches wrong string?

Tags: regex, haskell, lexical-analysis, alex

I'm trying to write lexer for an indentation-based grammar and I'm having trouble matching the indentation.

Here's my code:

```
{
module Lexer ( main ) where

import System.IO.Unsafe
}


%wrapper "monadUserState"

$whitespace = [\ \t\b]
$digit      = 0-9                                            -- digits
$alpha      = [A-Za-z]
$letter     = [a-zA-Z]                                       -- alphabetic characters
$ident      = [$letter $digit _]                             -- identifier character
$indent     = [\ \t]

@number     = [$digit]+
@identifier = $alpha($alpha|_|$digit)*

error:-

@identifier { mkL LVarId }

\n $whitespace* \n { skip }
\n $whitespace*    { setIndent }
$whitespace+       { skip }

{

data Lexeme = Lexeme AlexPosn LexemeClass (Maybe String)

instance Show Lexeme where
    show (Lexeme _ LEOF _)   = "  Lexeme EOF"
    show (Lexeme p cl  mbs) = " Lexeme class=" ++ show cl ++ showap p ++ showst mbs
      where
        showap pp = " posn=" ++ showPosn pp
        showst Nothing  = ""
        showst (Just s) = " string=" ++ show s

instance Eq Lexeme where
    (Lexeme _ cls1 _) == (Lexeme _ cls2 _) = cls1 == cls2

showPosn :: AlexPosn -> String
showPosn (AlexPn _ line col) = show line ++ ':': show col

tokPosn :: Lexeme -> AlexPosn
tokPosn (Lexeme p _ _) = p

data LexemeClass
    = LVarId
    | LTIndent Int
    | LTDedent Int
    | LIndent
    | LDedent
    | LEOF
    deriving (Show, Eq)

mkL :: LexemeClass -> AlexInput -> Int -> Alex Lexeme
mkL c (p, _, _, str) len = return (Lexeme p c (Just (take len str)))

data AlexUserState = AlexUserState { indent :: Int }

alexInitUserState :: AlexUserState
alexInitUserState = AlexUserState 0

type Action = AlexInput -> Int -> Alex Lexeme

getLexerIndentLevel :: Alex Int
getLexerIndentLevel = Alex $ \s@AlexState{alex_ust=ust} -> Right (s, indent ust)

setLexerIndentLevel :: Int -> Alex ()
setLexerIndentLevel i = Alex $ \s@AlexState{alex_ust=ust} -> Right (s{alex_ust=(AlexUserState i)}, ())

setIndent :: Action
setIndent input@(p, _, _, str) i = do
    --let !x = unsafePerformIO $ putStrLn $ "|matched string: " ++ str ++ "|"
    lastIndent <- getLexerIndentLevel
    currIndent <- countIndent (drop 1 str) 0 -- first char is always \n
    if (lastIndent < currIndent) then
        do setLexerIndentLevel currIndent
           mkL (LTIndent (currIndent - lastIndent)) input i
    else if (lastIndent > currIndent) then
        do setLexerIndentLevel currIndent
           mkL (LTDedent (lastIndent - currIndent)) input i
    else alexMonadScan
  where
    countIndent str total
        | take 1 str == "\t" = do skip input 1
                                  countIndent (drop 1 str) (total+1)
        | take 4 str == "    " = do skip input 4
                                    countIndent (drop 4 str) (total+1)
        | otherwise = return total

alexEOF :: Alex Lexeme
alexEOF = return (Lexeme undefined LEOF Nothing)

scanner :: String -> Either String [Lexeme]
scanner str =
    let loop = do
        tok@(Lexeme _ cl _) <- alexMonadScan
        if (cl == LEOF)
            then return [tok]
            else do toks <- loop
                    return (tok:toks)
    in runAlex str loop

addIndentations :: [Lexeme] -> [Lexeme]
addIndentations (lex@(Lexeme pos (LTIndent c) _):ls) =
    concat [iter lex c, addIndentations ls]
  where iter lex c = if c == 0 then []
                     else (Lexeme pos LIndent Nothing):(iter lex (c-1))
addIndentations (lex@(Lexeme pos (LTDedent c) _):ls) =
    concat [iter lex c, addIndentations ls]
  where iter lex c = if c == 0 then []
                     else (Lexeme pos LDedent Nothing):(iter lex (c-1))
addIndentations (l:ls) = l:(addIndentations ls)
addIndentations [] = []


main = do
    s <- getContents
    return ()
    print $ fmap addIndentations (scanner s)

}
```

Problem is that in line `\n $whitespace*    { setIndent }`, regex matches wrong string and calls `setIndent` with this wrong string. For debugging purposes, I added `unsafePerformIO` in `setIndent` function, here's an example run of the program:

```
begin       
        first indent
|matched string: 
        first indent
                second indent
                second indent
dedent
dedent
|
|matched string: 
                second indent
dedent
|
|matched string: 
dedent
|
|matched string: 
|
Right [ Lexeme class=LVarId posn=1:1 string="begin", Lexeme class=LIndent posn=1:6, Lexeme class=LVarId posn=2:15 string="indent", Lexeme class=LIndent posn=2:21, Lexeme class=LDedent posn=3:30, Lexeme class=LDedent posn=3:30, Lexeme class=LVarId posn=4:1 string="dedent",  Lexeme EOF]
```

So `setIndent` is called with more than just whitespaces. And after it returns the lexeme for indentation, other part of the string is omitted.

Is this a bug in Alex? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So I haven't analysed your code in detail, but I did notice this:

```
setIndent :: Action
setIndent input@(p, _, _, str) i = do
    --let !x = unsafePerformIO $ putStrLn $ "|matched string: " ++ str ++ "|"
```

Note that `str` is the rest of the input, not just the current token.  To get the current token, you want `take i str`.  Perhaps this is giving you the impression that the token is matching more of the input than it really is.

We handle indentation in GHC's own lexer of course, so you might want to [look there for ideas](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Lexer.x) (although as you might expect it's rather large and complicated).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so I changed my code and now it's working on `take i str` but nothing changed. After the `setIndent` returns the indentation token, rest of the line is being omitted by Alex(since Alex action functions doesn't decide what will be the next part of input string, I don't think it's related with my `setIndent` function)

Comment: well, your regex says that it matches a newline followed by zero or more whitespace characters, and that looks like exactly what is happening in your debug output.

Comment: It matches the whitespace characters but it also matches some additional characters following whitespace characters and this characters is not being matched by regexes after the regex that mathes whitespace characters after newlines. If you actually run the code and type some indented lines(an indentation is 4 spaces of a tab character) you'll see that tokens after indentation tokens is being omitted somehow.